# R : How to fix y scale to get ordred an meaningfuls values comparing to its high?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis

I am trying to make a bar graph using this R code :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
#q2
d=data.frame(
rbind(as.data.frame(table(data$q2_a))[2,2],
as.data.frame(table(data$q2_b))[2,2],
as.data.frame(table(data$q2_c))[2,2],
as.data.frame(table(data$q2_d))[2,2],
as.data.frame(table(data$q2_e))[2,2],
as.data.frame(table(data$q2_f))[2,2],
as.data.frame(table(data$q2_g))[2,2],
as.data.frame(table(data$q2_h))[2,2]))
d[is.na(d)] <-0
colnames(d)="Freq"


 df=data.frame(Pourcentage=percent(d$Freq/61),Opération=c("Dépot",
"Virement national","Virement \n international",
"Versement","Retrait","Lettre de crédit","Encaissement chèque \n 
 en devises","Autres"))
 ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Opération, y=Pourcentage, fill=Opération)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.5)+ 
 geom_text(aes(label=Pourcentage), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3.5)+
 theme_minimal()+
 ggtitle("Quelle est la nature de vos opérations avec la Poste 
 Tunisienne ?")+scale_x_discrete(limits = df$Opération)
```

However my y-scale is extremely jumbled up for some reason.
but I don't know how to fix it.

[image: the output]

Comment: It is not reproducible for me. But it seems that your y-variable is discrete. Fix up your question so that everybody can reproduce your data (e.g. using `dput`).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're converting the numbers to formatted character percentages in the data frame, so the data becomes non-numeric. Instead, keep the data as numeric fractions, and use `scales::percent()` when creating the scales and labels in ggplot2, i.e. change the `geom_text` call to:

```
geom_text(aes(label = percent(Pourcentage), ...)
```

and add:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```